# can search engines crawl pure javascript apps?

Tags: javascript, json, user-interface, backbone.js

There's a lot of movement in UI toward pure javascript front-ends like backbone.js or javascript mvc. I know google has some guidelines for adding #hash tags to your urls to make them crawlable...but I'm curious if they can still crawl apps that don't follow this guideline.

I'm debating whether to use a template engine on server side or just use pure javascript solution with json requests to an api. I want people to find pages on my site when searching.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they can, **if you describe for them how to do it.** Detailed answer for google is [here](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)

You may use hashtags/ html snapshots of every dynamic state.
There is many other ways to make pure js site crawled. You only need to chose one, which better fits your needs.

Comment: i'd rather not be forced to follow some standard defined by google....a path is a path.

Comment: it is not a standard(yet), but google purpose it as a standart. And IMHO, it will be same as with SPDY.

Answer (score 0):

[Distal Templates](http://code.google.com/p/distal/) makes a static webpage, which is indexable by Google, into a dynamic page using JSON and templates.

Comment: You'd have to run this on backend.